# Hops comparison resource

Tags: hops

Going back I used to use the very handy site Union Hops to compare different hops, see alpha content, hop oils, tasting notes etc.. After being bought out by Yakima Chief I had been using their site YCH Hops to compare hops. Now that has disappeared and just redirects to Yakima Chief's main website which contains no such useful information. There is a countdown to 44 days away to a shop opening but nothing yet on the hops themselves.

**Is there another hop comparison tool out there?**

I want to be able to categorise hops by bittering/aroma/dual purpose, by different tasting notes (e.g. Citrus, Earthy, Floral etc), alpha acid content and all the usual hop characteristics.

Short of painstakingly going through the web and compiling this data from multiple sources into my own spreadsheet I am hoping there is an online resource somewhere I can use that I just haven't found yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found a handy hops list on Brew Your Owns website.  It gives the option to sort hops by beer style use.  Also contains some of the useful stats that you might be looking for.  Here's a link

https://byo.com/resource/hops/

Comment: It's pretty good is that resource for the number of hops it has and if nothing else comes up it is what I'll probably have to use. However, I'm preferably trying to find one which compares more aspects of the hop which are useful. I.e. Storability, Total hop oils, content such as Humulene, Myrcene etc.

Comment: I like to look up hops there and then I'll find them in beersmith to get more of their stats.